# When to use multiple ng-app in angular?

Tags: angularjs

Is it good practice to use only single ng-app per page(or) can we use multiple ng-app per page in angular application? If we can use multiple ng-app, When to use multiple ng-app per page in angular application?

Comment: My question is about, in what cases should we use multiple ng-app?

Answer (score 0):

One good reason to do that is by having two angular applications, **the digest cycle of each would take half the time**. However this is only to do if the two applications are totally separated and **you don't want them to interact** with each other.

Other than for performances reason, I wouldn't recommend to do that. However, be sure to create many modules to better separate your logic, though have one root module that would resolve all dependencies.

TL;DR: It is not a good practive and would confuse more the developpers (including you), but can have a good impact on performances.